# Running all tests at once result in some of them failing, but when they're being fired alone, then they work fine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, xunit, visual-studio-2019

I have some weird problem that some of my tests are failing whenever I `Run all` tests, but when I start them 1 by 1 then everything works fine

here's code which fails at seeding `InMemoryDatabase`

It has to add some `Permission`s to `Permissions` table and then create `Group`s that have many to many relation to permissions

Basically one Group can have many permissions, and one permission can be used in many groups

But the problem is that

`.Single` throws

> Sequence contains more than one element

when all tests are running at once, but everything is ok when it's running alone

Any idea?

```
public class Tests : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Context _context;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    }

    public Tests()
    {
        var o = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Context>();
        o.UseInMemoryDatabase("testDb");
        _context = new Context(o.Options);
        _context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        _context.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    [Fact]

    public async void myTest()
    {
        Initializer.InitializePermissions(_context);
        Initializer.InitializeGroups(_context);
        (...)
    }
}

public static class Initializer
{
    public static void InitializePermissions(Context context)
    {
        var permissionNames = new List<string>
        {
            "CanCreateNewProduct",
            "CanRemoveProduct",
        };

        foreach (var permission in permissionNames)
        {
            context.Permissions.Add(new Permission(permission));
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }   

    public static void InitializeGroups(Context context)
    {
        var groups = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        groups.add("Admin", new List<string>{"CanRemoveProduct"};

        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            foreach (var permissionName in group.Value)
            {
                var permission = context.Permissions.Single(x => x.Name == permissionName);

                group.GroupPermissions.Add
                (
                    new Many2Many
                    {
                        Group = group,
                        GroupId = group.Id,
                        Permission = permission,
                        PermissionId = permission.Id
                    }
                );
            }

            context.Groups.Add(new Group(group.Key, permissions);
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like your tests are sharing state.  Each test should be entirely isolated and not depend on external or shared state.  Maybe instead of using a single `static` in-memory structure, use the same structure but instance-based and each test creates/uses/disposes its own instance?  Each DB would need to be isolated too, so `UseInMemoryDatabase("testDb")` would need individual DB names for each test.

Comment: Changing `UseInMemoryDatabase("testDb")` to `UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());` was enough Oo, thanks! If you want, then write it as an answer, so I'll be able to accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that your tests are using shared state.

(Incidentally, if you're ever wondering why a lot of programmers will go to great lengths to avoid using anything `static` and you feel their objects, dependency injections, etc. are overly complex when they could just "make it static"... This is why.)

Your `Initializer` *can* probably remain `static`, as long as it doesn't internally maintain state.  Which it appears not to at least at a glance, since you pass an instance of a database context to it.  But as you continue to work in your system it's important to maintain that this initializer maintains no state itself across tests.

This then brings us to the in-memory database itself:

```
o.UseInMemoryDatabase("testDb");
```

These are globally accessible across the application.  *But* you can give them unique names.  For example:

```
var dbName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
o.UseInMemoryDatabase(dbName);
```

With this, each DB context should have a unique database which you can later reference with `dbName` anywhere you might need that.  So even though all of the databases are technically globally available, any given test only knows about its own and can only reference its own.

(Keep an eye on performance of course.  If you find yourself creating large complex databases, which you shouldn't for small individual tests, then creating *many* of those databases at once might slow things down.)